# How I can export data automatically in browsers dev tools network fetch?

Tags: json, xmlhttprequest

I am working as a data analysist and I am junior too. The following is my question/problem.

I want to access some data from the requested headers from dev network tabs in browsers. How can I export those data automatically even with certain changes on latter request?

Let me explore more,
For example, I am navigating a site. Then I am going to access development tools of the browser and then I navigate to the network tab with fetch XHR, after that I want to export the response of it automatically. how can I do that?

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'automatically'? Not by doing a manual export, like so? https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/reference/#save-as-har

Comment: Would this extension help you? https://www.webqsee.com/